# Continue while loops bash

Tags: bash, while-loop, nested, do-while

I'm having some problems with my bash script. I having inner while loops in the bash script. But i'm having some problems with continue to the first loop or to the second loop.

I want for example: When the first inner loop is not true continue to the second inner loop. But still every-time just one of the loops is working. So both loops should working all the time when the right event happens.

This is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash    

counterSearch=0
counterIssue=0
counterPassed=0
counterFailed=0
counterSearchPassed=0
counterSearchFailed=0
counterIssuePassed=0
counterIssueFailed=0
counterTotal=0
counterHourly=0
counterAddHourly=0
declare -a hourlyScan=('1' '0' '5' '0' '7' '2' '0' '13' '0' '18' '0' '0' '7' '0' '6' '0' '0' '1' '3' '0' '0' '0' '3' '0')    

logDir=/var/atlassian/application-data/jira/log
logIng=$logDir/atlassian-ing-security.log
logJira=$logDir/atlassian-jira-security.log    


function abc {    

while true; do
currentMinute=$(date +%S)
currentHour=$(date +%k)
currentDay=$(date +%u)
currentWeek=$(date +%W)    

    if [[ $currentMinute == 00 ]]; then    

    if [ ${#hourlyScan[@]} -eq 24 ]; then
       unset hourlyScan[23]
       hourlyScan=($counterHourly "${hourlyScan[@]}")
       counterHourly=0    

       for i in "${!hourlyScan[@]}"; do
          $cliScript --server $cliServer --user $cliUser --password $cliPass --action modifyPage --space "" --title "" \
          --findReplaceRegex "<tr><td>$i</td><td>(\d*)</td></tr>:<tr><td>$i</td><td>${hourlyScan[$i]}</td></tr>"
       done
    else
      continue 2
    fi    

    fi


    tail -n0 -F $logJira | \
    while read line ; do    

    if echo "$line" | grep -e "/rest/api/2/search.*PASSED" 1>/dev/null 2>&1 ; then
       echo "$date - Search and passed API action" >> $logIng
       counterSearch=$((counterSearch+1))
       counterPassed=$((counterPassed+1))
       counterHourly=$((counterHourly+1))
       counterTotal=$((counterTotal+1))
       echo "$date - Total Passed API Authentication: $counterPassed" >> $logIng
       echo "$date - Total search API actions: $counterSearch" >> $logIng    

    elif echo "$line" | grep -e "/rest/api/2/search.*FAILED" 1>/dev/null 2>&1 ; then
       echo "$date - Search and failed API action" >> $logIng
       counterSearch=$((counterSearch+1))
       counterFailed=$((counterFailed+1))
       counterHourly=$((counterHourly+1))
       counterTotal=$((counterTotal+1))
       echo "$date - Total Failed API Authentication: $counterFailed" >> $logIng
       echo "$date - Total search API actions: $counterSearch" >> $logIng    

    elif echo "$line" | grep -e "/rest/api/2/issue.*PASSED" 1>/dev/null 2>&1 ; then
       echo "$date - Issue and Passed API action" >> $logIng
       counterIssue=$((counterIssue+1))
       counterPassed=$((counterPassed+1))
       counterHourly=$((counterHourly+1))
       counterTotal=$((counterTotal+1))
       echo "$date - Total Passed API Authentication: $counterPassed" >> $logIng
       echo "$date - Total issue API actions: $counterIssue" >> $logIng    

    elif echo "$line" | grep -e "/rest/api/2/issue.*FAILED" 1>/dev/null 2>&1 ; then
       echo "$date -Issue and Failed API action" >> $logIng
       counterIssue=$((counterIssue+1))
       counterFailed=$((counterFailed+1))
       counterHourly=$((counterHourly+1))
       counterTotal=$((counterTotal+1))
       echo "$date - Total Failed API Authentication: $counterFailed" >> $logIng
       echo "$date - Total issue API actions: $counterIssue" >> $logIng
    else
      continue 2
    fi
    done    

done    

}    

abc
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use the inner loop to another function and call it whenever is needed.

Comment: So you mean having 3 functions. And call the two inner loops in the other function? Thank you.

Comment: Yes that would be better option and you have better control. Accept the answer if this helps.

Comment: So in the first while loop add a if/else that call the other while loop functions? I will try it and offcourse accept if it works!

Comment: Sadly enough i didn't work with my code. Do you have a example?